# Efficient way to generate a table in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, html-table, data-representation

This question might sound a lot vague. What I'm looking for is a way to generate a html `<table></table>`.

I need to build this table:

[image: Table]

Actually the top row is a header and the first two columns are headers too.

For every cell starting from (3,2), I execute a 'count' query.

Now I'm doing a very ugly loop to build a 2D-array. I've got the feeling that has to be nicer. In the near future I have to put a link below every 'counted' integer which links to another table to present the rows related to the integer.

This is how I do it now:
I'm just looping trough various `Dictionaries(Of String,String)` to generate the 2D array. To build the arrays I use two variables to know where in the table I am: `Dim lv_TRow As Integer = 0` and `Dim lv_TCol As Integer = 0`.

There must be a better way. Maybe converting these to objects or something I don't know yet.

Can you help to make this nicer?

```
Public Function build2DArray() As String(,)
    Dim lv_Tabel(15, 4) As String


    Dim riskLevels As New Dictionary(Of String, String) ' Kan gebruikt worden in WHERE
    riskLevels.Add("Extreem", 5)
    riskLevels.Add("Hoog", 4)
    riskLevels.Add("Normaal", 3)
    riskLevels.Add("Laag", 2)
    riskLevels.Add("Gering", 1)

    Dim algStss As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    algStss.Add("Gestart", 0)
    algStss.Add("Geanalyseerd", 0)
    algStss.Add("Opgelost", 0)

    Dim incStss As New Dictionary(Of String, String) ' Kan gebruikt worden in WHERE
    incStss.Add("Gestart", "L14_IncSts IN (1,2)")
    incStss.Add("Geanalyseerd", "L14_IncSts IN (3,4,5,6,7)")
    incStss.Add("Opgelost", "L14_IncSts IN (8)")

    Dim prmStss As New Dictionary(Of String, String) ' Kan gebruikt worden in WHERE
    prmStss.Add("Gestart", "L24_StsIdt IN (1)")
    prmStss.Add("Geanalyseerd", "L24_StsIdt IN (2,3,4,5,6)")
    prmStss.Add("Opgelost", "L24_StsIdt IN (7)")

    Dim wzgStss As New Dictionary(Of String, String) ' Kan gebruikt worden in WHERE
    wzgStss.Add("Gestart", "L38_StsIdt IN (1,2)")
    wzgStss.Add("Geanalyseerd", "L38_StsIdt IN (3,4,5,6,7)")
    wzgStss.Add("Opgelost", "L38_StsIdt IN (8,9,10,11)")

    Dim headers As New Dictionary(Of String, String) ' Kan gebruikt worden in FROM
    headers.Add("Risiconiveau", 0)
    headers.Add("Status", 0)
    headers.Add("Incident", "Inc")
    headers.Add("Probleem", "Prm")
    headers.Add("Wijziging", "Wzg")

    Dim lv_Dtb As New Database
    'lv_Dtb.ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM Ris")

    Dim lv_TRow As Integer = 0
    Dim lv_TCol As Integer = 0

    For Each header As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In headers
        lv_Tabel(lv_TRow, lv_TCol) = header.Key
        lv_TCol += 1
    Next

    lv_TCol = 0
    lv_TRow = 1

    For Each riskLevel As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In riskLevels
        lv_Tabel(lv_TRow + 1, lv_TCol) = riskLevel.Key
        lv_TCol += 1

        For Each algSts As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In algStss
            lv_Tabel(lv_TRow, lv_TCol) = algSts.Key
            lv_TRow += 1
        Next
        lv_TRow -= 3
        lv_TCol += 1

        For Each incSts As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In incStss
            Try
                Dim dataset As DataSet = lv_Dtb.ExecuteQuery(QryString(1, incSts.Value, riskLevel.Value))
                lv_Tabel(lv_TRow, lv_TCol) = dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0) 'eerste query
            Catch err As SqlException
                Logger.Log(err.Message)
                lv_Tabel(lv_TRow, lv_TCol) = "err"
            End Try
            lv_TRow += 1
        Next
        lv_TRow -= 3
        lv_TCol += 1

        For Each prmSts As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In prmStss
            Try
                Dim dataset As DataSet = lv_Dtb.ExecuteQuery(QryString(2, prmSts.Value, riskLevel.Value))
                lv_Tabel(lv_TRow, lv_TCol) = dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0) 'eerste query
            Catch err As SqlException
                Logger.Log(err.Message)
                lv_Tabel(lv_TRow, lv_TCol) = "err"
            End Try
            lv_TRow += 1
        Next
        lv_TRow -= 3
        lv_TCol += 1

        For Each wzgSts As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In wzgStss
            Try
                Dim dataset As DataSet = lv_Dtb.ExecuteQuery(QryString(3, wzgSts.Value, riskLevel.Value))
                lv_Tabel(lv_TRow, lv_TCol) = dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0) 'eerste query
            Catch err As SqlException
                Logger.Log(err.Message)
                lv_Tabel(lv_TRow, lv_TCol) = "err"
            End Try
            lv_TRow += 1
        Next

        lv_TCol -= 4
    Next

    lv_Dtb.CloseConnection()

    Return lv_Tabel
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Datatable

```
 Dim dtb As New DataTable
 dtb.Columns.Add("Risiconiveau", GetType(String))
 dtb.Columns.Add("Status", GetType(String))
 dtb.Columns.Add("Incident", GetType(Integer))
 dtb.Columns.Add("Probleem", GetType(Integer))
 dtb.Columns.Add("Wijziging", GetType(Integer))

 dtb.Rows.Add("Extreem", "Geanalyseerd", 0, 0, 0)
 dtb.Rows.Add("Extreem", "Opgelost", 0, 0, 0)
 dtb.Rows.Add("Extreem", "Gestart", 0, 0, 0)

 For Each drw As DataRow In dtb.Rows
   If CStr(drw("Risiconiveau")) = "Extreem" And CInt(drw("Incident")) = 0 Then
     drw("Opgelost") = CInt(drw("Opgelost")) + 1
   End If

 Next drw
 dtb.Dispose()
```